Pinter set theory exercise 2.5.10
Pinter set theory exercise 2.5.10 is to prove $(A-B)^C=A^C-B^C$ where $A^C$ is the set of functions from $C$ to $A$.
It's easy enough to show $(A-B)^C \subseteq A^C-B^C$, but I believe the reverse direction is not correct. For suppose $A=\{1,2,3\}, B=\{3,4\},C=\{2,3\}$ and $f$ is the identity function on $\{2,3\}$. Then $f \in A^C-B^C$ but $f \notin (A-B)^C$. Is my conclusion correct?
Edit: Even the forwards direction is not correct if we allow $C=\emptyset$. For then $\emptyset \in (A-B)^C, \emptyset \in A^C, \emptyset \in B^C$ and so $\emptyset \notin A^C-B^C$

Yes, I agree with all of that.

Which is the definition of $A^C - B^C$? It is ${f - g : f \in A^C, g \in B^C }$?

It means $f \in A^C$ and $f \notin B^C$. I prefer the backslash notation, but I am using the same notation as the book,

@spaceisdarkgreen Then another wrong exercise in Pinter!. Pinter is actually quite a good book but seems to have some sloppy exercises.

Are you sure that $A^C$ is used here to denote the set of all functions from $C$ to $A$? When discussing subsets of some fixed "universe" (for example, the real numbers), it is common to denote the complement of $A$ by $A^C$ or $A^c$ or $A^\complement$.  That said, the statement is also false under this interpretation.

@PaulSinclair I have Pinter in hard copy, but it’s also not too hard to find online. “ 2.34 Definition If $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary classes, the symbol $B^A$ refers to the class of all functions from $A$ to $B$.”.

Yes. Nothing I said contradicts that definition. I am pointing out that sometimes (quite often, actually), notations can have more than one meaning (such as $(a,b)$ indicating a point on the plane or an open interval on the real line). I do not know if Pinter ever uses the universal complement notation. But if he does, then you would have to determine what $A^C$ means in this question from the full context of the question, not from whatever definition you happened across first.

Ok, I can see where you are coming from, but this definition immediately precedes the question. The complement of a class $A$ is defined in 1.19 as $A’$.
