Every poset has a maximal well ordered subset
I am working my way through the proof of the captioned statement. It is stated more precisely here. I am using the hints and workings on the link. I can show steps 1 and 2. And I can show by Zorn's Lemma that $\mathcal{A}$ (not $A$) has a maximal element.  But I don't see how that implies $A$ has a maximal well ordered subset. I am assuming that "a maximal well ordered subset" is a subset that is maximal by inclusion (but may be wrong).
In fact, if I interpret the theorem to mean that $A$ has a maximum well-ordered subset by inclusion, I don't think it is correct. Let $A$ be the set of integers ordered by $\le$. Then $(A,\le)$ is a poset. Suppose $B$ is a maximal well-ordered subset of $A$. Let $x$ be the least element of $B$. Let $B_1=B \cup \{x-1\}$. Then $B_1$ is well ordered and $B \subset B_1$ so $B$ is not maximal.
Is there another interpretation I am missing here?

In my opinion the choice of words is poor, but they mean maximal with respect to the relation $\preceq$, which essentially is that $A\preceq B$ if and only if $A$ is an initial segment of $B$. For instance, in $\Bbb Z$ all subsets that are bounded below and unbounded above will be maximal well-orders with respect to $\preceq$. Namely, $B$ and $B\cup{\min (B)-1}$ are not $\preceq$-comparable.

@AnneBauval I am trying to resolve the conflict between the link you provided and the link in my post. Is there another interpretation of this theorem which is correct? Or could a a version which is less ambiguous be correct? The link you provided is saying one interpretation is incorrect, and the link I provided is to a text book exercise stating the (apparently) same theorem. Do you believe that the theorem in my link is incorrect?

Pinter's theorem 5.17 p.118 is just false.

Ah, maybe I should stop using this book [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4937817/pinter-set-theory-exercise-2-5-10]

@SassatelliGiulio Interestingly the next exercise in this book is to prove theorem 5.18 using the captioned  theorem. This can be done if we interpret the captioned theorem in the way you suggested (which I believe is a true statement).

@Porky I don't have the book. If they indeed mean maximal by $\subseteq$, then by all means it's false and your counterexample stands (see also the negative integers, where every well-ordered subset is contained in a well-ordered subset of strictly larger cardinality).
